# General exception caught instead of the more specific EmptyStackException

Tags: java, exception, stack

This is my method to pop() the top element of a stack:

```
public T pop() throws EmptyStackException {

   if (this.isEmpty()) {

      throw new EmptyStackException("Empty stack - cannot pop()");

   }

   // I have code here to pop the element if the stack is not empty.

}
```

In another file, there is code to test this method, which includes this:

```
public int exceptionTest() {

   int exceptionVal = 0;

   try {

      // Code attempting to pop an element from an empty stack.

   }

   catch (EmptyStackException e) {

      ++exceptionVal;

   }

   catch (Exception e) {

      --exceptionVal;

   }

   return exceptionVal;

}
```

The code above returns -1 when called - why is a general exception being caught, instead of the more specific EmptyStackException?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you log the exception being caught? Most likely you get some other exception (maybe from isEmpty, maybe from test method)

Comment: Just ran some more tests... it seems to have been throwing a null pointer exception which doesn't make sense, because if top = null, then numItems = 0, so isEmpty() should return true, causing the EmptyStackException to be thrown...

Comment: It seems like the if statement is not executing for some reason, so it tries to continue with the pop, which throws a null pointer exception.  I will try and see what the issue is, but isEmpty() should be working fine.

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but I figured it out!  I had an issue in my code for the pop() method.  Thanks for the help anyways!